# Shared worker do share variables

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I've been reading some documents about shared worker context. Lots of them point out shared worker do not share variables, which means they can not use each other variables.
However, my experiment againsts that.

## Parent worker

```
var port = new SharedWorker('worker.js').port;
port.start();
port.postMessage('Hello');
```

## Worker

```
var ports = [];
onconnect = function(e){
    var port = e.ports[0];
    port.start();
    ports.push(port);
    console.log('Number of tabs: '+ports.length);
};
```

`ports.length` keeps increasing when I open more tabs, which means `ports` is shared between workers.

Could anybody please explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe SharedWorker creates a single worker which is accessed from multiple parents, so its not sharing variables since its a single SharedWorker process sharing parents

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Workers have independent javascript *contexts* that cannot *share* variables.
The `ports` variable is part of the SharedWorker's javascript *API*, not it's javascript *context*.

Note that all workers can *pass* variables via messaging.
DedicatedWorkers can *pass by reference* using Transferrables, but SharedWorkers can only *pass by value*, since they use async serialized buffers (`ports`) to do the actual messaging.