# Wakanda Shared Storage equivalent in v10

Tags: wakanda

Due to compatibility issues, my project must remain in Wakanda 10. What is the best technique to keep a variable consistent across multiple server threads? For instance, if I want to make an object literal that can be modified, how can I best ensure the data is updated across all Wakanda Server threads?

For now, I am going to write the value to the datastore as a work around. Any better suggestions would be appreciated. Would a shared worker help me?

Answer (score 1):

Web workers can't access global variables. you can handle communication between web workers via Message Passing.

To make an object available for all workers you can :

1. Pass the object from a worker to another one using **postMessage**;
2. Store the object in the database.

I believe the the best way is to store your variable in the datastore. it's more simple especially if you have a lot of workers.

Here are some related discussions:

- [Shared worker do share variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688439/shared-worker-do-share-variables)
- [Sharing variables between web workers? [global variables?]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262681/sharing-variables-between-web-workers-global-variables)

Comment: Is it safe to assume, based on your answer that a global variable on the server side will be updated in all threads? This is not what I was experiencing. Where would you declare this global (bootstrap?)